# Making polymer dom-repeat to work when a HTML block is added using .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0, dom-repeat

I am working on a polymer app where I need to fetch some HTML code block of code from external file and append to active file. I have specified the content to add myself.

Below is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

        <dom-module id="trail-app">
            <template>
                <style>
                </style>

                <button on-tap="loadContent">click</button>
                <button on-tap="showContent">show</button>

                <template is="dom-repeat" items='{{celsius}}'>
                    <div>[[item]]</div>
                </template>

                <div id="content"></div>

            </template> 

        <script>
                 Polymer({
                 is: "trail-app",

                 properties:{
                        celsius:{}
                 },

                 ready:function(){
                    this.celsius = ["36","37","38","39","40","41"];
                 },

                 loadContent:function(data){
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{Celsius}}">'+
                    '<div>[[item]]</div>'+
                    '</template>';
                 },

                 showContent:function(){
                    console.log(document.getElementById("content").innerHTML);
                 },

            });
        </script> 
        </dom-module>
        <trail-app></trail-app>
 </body>
</html>
```

when I loop through `celsius` using dom-repeat its working fine.
but if the same code is added using `document.getElementById("content").innerHTML` its giving

> Polymer::Attributes: couldnt decode Array as JSON warning.

How to resolve this.

Comment: Will you be getting `dom-repeat` from external file or do you want to append the code that you get in `dom-repeat`

Comment: i am getting entire div which has dom repeat from external file

Answer (score 0):

So I've addressed dynamic content like this using the templatizer behavior (https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Templatizer).

To use, create just a plain template with your dom-repeat inside that. Then in your loadContent method that's where you'll apply templatize and then stamp the template into the DOM.

```
<template id="repeatTempl">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{Celsius}}">
        <div>[[item]]</div>
    </template>
</template>
```

Include the Templatizer behavior:

```
behaviors: [Polymer.Templatizer]
```

Then your loadContent method would look something like this:

```
loadContent: function(data) {
    var templ = this.$.repeatTempl;
    this.templatize(templ);
    var elem = this.stamp({Celsius: data});
    Polymer.dom(this.$.content).appendChild(elem.root);
}
```